# Pie chart -custom event for legendItemClick-highchart

Tags: jquery, highcharts

Please have a look at the jsfiddle [**`here`**](http://jsfiddle.net/8T7Ew/) to understand what I am upto.
To get the `legendItemClick` working I need to click on the colored buttons in the legend.

But in this sample even clicking on the texts(right to the colored buttons) fires `legendItemClick`  click event.

what should I do to get the event fired even when I click on the text?

Comment: The js fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/8T7Ew/

Comment: I don't know how to add this link in the post itself can some one edit?

Answer (score 4):

According to documentation legendItemClick is not supported in pie chart http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.events.legendItemClick but you can use workaround: http://jsfiddle.net/JkDrM/13/

```
    $(chart.series[0].data).each(function(i, e) {
        e.legendItem.on('click', function() {
            if (!e.sliced) {
                alert('hide slice');
            } else {
                alert('show slice');
            }
            e.slice(!e.sliced);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have not framed your question correctly!  "// some code here to achieve my goal" what goal?