# Highcharts show legend just once

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Sounds odd but I have these 3 charts in a single chart.

The problem is that if I use `showInLegend:true` to each series then I have 9 items in legend.

I want to display `Urban, Rural, Nothing` just one time each.

Here is my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/HpdwR/1298/

```
 series: [{
        data: [{
            name: 'Urban',
            color: 'red',
            y: 4
        }, {
            name: 'Nothing',
            color: 'blue',
            y: 2
        }, {
            name: 'Rural',
            color: 'green',
            y: 4,
        }],
        size: '130px',
        innerSize: '115px',
        center: ['12%'],
        name: 'first',
        showInLegend: true
    }, {
        data: [{
            color: 'red',
            y: 1
        }, {
            color: 'blue',
            y: 4
        }, {
            color: 'green',
            y: 5
        }],
        size: '130px',
        innerSize: '115px',
        center: ['50%'],
        name: 'second',
        showInLegend: true
    }, {
        data: [{
            color: 'red',
            y: 6
        }, {
            color: 'blue',
            y: 2
        }, {
            color: 'green',
            y: 2
        }],
        size: '130px',
        innerSize: '115px',
        center: ['88%'],
        name: 'third',
        showInLegend: true
    }]
```

Comment: You can evaluate this example: http://jsfiddle.net/u7FQS/15/ to achieve combined legend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find an elegant way to do this, or a built-in solution (maybe there is one, but I couldn't find it...)

Here's a hack that hides the extra legends, and links the hover event. I've disabled the click events for simplicity.

```
// Legend Hack
$('g.highcharts-legend-item:nth-child(n+4)').css('visibility', 'hidden');
$('g.highcharts-legend-item').hover(function() {
    var i = $(this).index();
    $('g.highcharts-legend-item').eq(i+3).trigger('mouseover');
    $('g.highcharts-legend-item').eq(i+6).trigger('mouseover');
}, function() {
    var i = $(this).index();
    $('g.highcharts-legend-item').eq(i+3).trigger('mouseout');
    $('g.highcharts-legend-item').eq(i+6).trigger('mouseout');
});
$('g.highcharts-legend-item *').click(function() { return false; });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HpdwR/1303/

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the best option here would hide the extra legends so only one of them will be displayed. In order to have the control over the other charts with the displayed legend (that is currently controlling only one chart), you should write an event listener when clicking on the legend and ask it to have effect on the rest of the charts.

HOWEVER, the issue is that "legendItemClick" that is responsible for the event listener on the legend's click event is not working when using the pie chart. Therefore, you should catch it with jquery.. an example can be seen here https://stackoverflow.com/a/16099935/1138430